# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] and Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I am beginner in Angular JS , when I start creating module and controller , I am unable to print my message, and below is my code

```js
var myModule = angular.module("myFirst");

myModule.controller = ("cont", function($scope){
$scope.message = "Hi This is my first angular JS Learn ";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="myFirst">
<head>
<title>This is Angular JS tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

 </head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="cont">
{{message}}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can any one please explain , what is the issue caused ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add empty dependencies

```
var myModule = angular.module("myFirst",[]);
```

Also controller should be,

```
myModule.controller("cont", function($scope){
   $scope.message = "Hi This is my first angular JS Learn ";
});
```

```js
var myModule = angular.module("myFirst",[]);

myModule.controller("cont", function($scope){
$scope.message = "Hi This is my first angular JS Learn ";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="myFirst">
<head>
<title>This is Angular JS tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

 </head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="cont">
{{message}}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unable to get what are all the changes , you have done in the code . Can you please differentiate it. I got the empty injector

Comment: @ManjulaD I Have mentioned in the answer, you can expand snippet and check

Comment: click the tick which appears next to answer

Comment: Can you please explain why do we need injector? While creating module,  If it is going to be empty, why I can not leave ? Please explain if you wish and If it is lengthy one and about basics you can refer me a link. Thanks.

Comment: angular app without dependency  is to retrieve an existing module, whereas injecting  []  is to create a new module without any module dependency. you can add me on skype if you need any help related to angular. id:sajee4ever Regards